# How to lose damage from colliding with enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

Hi I'm very new to unity and C# so any help at all is greatly appreciated! I am trying to make my enemy (prefab is named snowman) and my player (prefab is named Santa) collide. When this happens, the player should lose damage in its healthbar. The healthbar is showing up but I just am so lost on how to make it lose health when it collides with the snowman.

Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour {
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public int maxHealth = 30;
    public int currentHealth;
    //private HealthBar healthBar;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    
    void TakeDamage(int damage) {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetHealth(currentHealth);
        // healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }

    void Start() {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
        // healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }

    void Update() {
        if (isLocalPlayer) {
            if (characterController.isGrounded) {
                // We are grounded, so recalculate
                // move direction directly from axes
                moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
                moveDirection *= speed;

                if (Input.GetButton("Jump")) {
                    moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
                }
            }
            // if ()
            //  {
            //     TakeDamage (10);
            //  }
            void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
                TakeDamage (10);
            }
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

            characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
        }

        void TakeDamage(int damage) {
            currentHealth -= damage;
            FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetHealth(currentHealth);
            // healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
        }
    }

    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer() {
        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().setTarget(gameObject.transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have done? i.e. `TakeDamage`

Comment: does the code compile?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay it does compile but when i play the game and touch the snowman, nothing happens to my healthbar

Comment: @MickyD when i play the game and the player touches the snowman, nothing happens to the healthbar

Comment: Why are your methods **nested** inside of the `Update` method?!

Answer (score 0):

Move `TakeDamage` and `OnCollisionEnter` to the class scope. Also I suggest to remove network features for the moment. Suggested code to meve on below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : Monobehaviour {
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public int maxHealth = 30;
    public int currentHealth;
    //private HealthBar healthBar;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    void Start() {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
        // healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }

    void Update() {
        if (isLocalPlayer) {
            if (characterController.isGrounded) {
                // We are grounded, so recalculate
                // move direction directly from axes
                moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
                moveDirection *= speed;

                if (Input.GetButton("Jump")) {
                    moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
                }
            }
            // if ()
            //  {
            //     TakeDamage (10);
            //  }
            
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

            characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
        }
    }


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
            TakeDamage (10);
    }

    void TakeDamage(int damage) {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetHealth(currentHealth);
        // healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }

    public void Start() {
        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().setTarget(gameObject.transform);
    }
}
```

For a start remove the `OnCollisionEnter` and the `TakeDamage` from the `Update`, you need them to be in the class scope.

On the other hand take into account the code format for the code readability. If the format is messy and the code not readable you are discouraging potential helpers to help you out! good luck

Comment: I've added those into my class scope underneath the private movement variable but now I have an error saying "TakeDamage" does not exist in this current context. I'm wondering if you know of an easier way to code that I take damage when colliding with my enemy? Thanks for all the help sofar - and yes I will definitely work on code format neatness

Comment: post the code in the question

Comment: public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public int maxHealth = 30;
    public int currentHealth;
  //  private HealthBar healthBar;

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
      TakeDamage (10);
    }

    void Start()
    {  Sorry I'm not sure how to fix this formatting for replies

Comment: edit the code in the question

Comment: Consider editing your answer to show what the code _should_ look like and more importantly so that it _compiles_.

Comment: true, thanks. Code edited in the answer

Comment: I also suggest changing `NetworkBehaviour` by `MonoBehaviour` and `public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()` by `public void Start() `, unless you are looking forward to program the net/multiplayer of your game before you can run it locally. Edited in the code of the answer proposal so that you are able to move on